# firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have connected my android application with firebase and enabled phone authentication on the console. However when I import

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
```

It can't find the class PhoneAuthProvider.
Note that it can find other classes such as EmailAuthProvider and FirebaseAuthProvider.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

is listed in the app dependencies.

Please let me know if I need to provide any other information to get help as well.

Comment: have u tried the latest version for auth "compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'"

Comment: @vivekverma thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone number authentication was [added in version 11.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  You will have to upgrade to at least that version.

> SDK Version 11.0.0 - June 7, 2017
>
> - Added the getPhoneNumber() and updatePhoneNumber() methods to the FirebaseUser class, and also added the getPhoneNumber() method to the
>     UserInfo class. These methods get and update the phone numbers of
>     users.
> - Added the PhoneAuthCredential, PhoneAuthProvider, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken, and
>     PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks classes to
>     support authentication using phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I used the firebase assistant to install firebase. How can I update it?

Comment: @Yashovardhan: Edit the app module build.gradle file.  In the `dependencies` block, make the needed changes to the version numbers. Change all Firebase and Google Play libraries to be at least 11.0.0.  Use the same version number for all.

Comment: Thanks!! I've used 11.+ To get it working (although Android studio does not promote the use of + but it was the only way to avoid redownloading the entire Google play package). Thanks once again!